# Definition of Conway's Game of Life / Cellular Automata

Tags: terminology, conways-game-of-life, cellular-automata

This is not actually a programming question, but one the programming community can help me with.

I need to write a *short* sentence highlighting the implications or purpose(s) of cellular automata / Conway's game of life to the ordinary public, in order to incite interest into my adaptation of it.

I have written this, is this correct, can I say it better?

> Despite its name, Conway's Game of Life is not a game, but a mathematical model for displaying emergence in chaos theory.

That's kind of wrong I know, but I'm not a scientist or mathematician!

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Conway's Game of Life demonstrates how a community can exhibit interesting behaviours when each member of that community obeys the same, very simple, rules."

maybe

Answer (score 1):

```
Despite it's name, Conway's Game of Life is not a game, 
but a mathematical model showing apparently complex 
behavior arising from a small set of simple rules.
```

Perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

How about

"Conway's Game of Life is not a game, but a system of simple rules under which a pattern can evolve in complex ways."

or

"...but a simple set of rules that can give rise to complex behavior."